# Invoke a java main class when weblogic server starts

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I have a java class has a main method. I want this main method to be executed whenever I start the WebLogic server.

Also I would like to have this class exit safely if I stop the WebLogic server.

I am not sure how to deploy this simple java application to WebLogic server or there is a way to configure the WebLogic server to call a jar file. What is the best way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure WLS to [call a specific Java class](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24401_02/taskhelp/startup_shutdown/ConfigureStartupAndShutdownClasses.html) on startup and/or shutdown via the admin console. The class must be on the WLS class path, so making modifications to that class involves a rolling node restart (and the ability to put the file on the class path startup scripts, of course).

Comment: Thank you. I check this method. It looks simple and very good for calling the main method at a server start. However I am having a new issue here, I would like to have control of the WebLogic server to stop this main process. I see inside deployment->control tab, there are start and stop services buttons. I had an EJB was used by an OBI server was deployed there and I can start and stop the service with some button clicks. Is it possible to deploy this main method like that and use the start and stop button to control it?

Comment: Apps inside web logic behave differently. You can configure an EAR to be aware about when its app server starts and stops, so you can execute code. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/lifecycle.htm